# How to collect errors from different functions?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am doing a project on C#. It's a project to send message using GSM Modem. In my project, I have several function that may give errors. I have used a string variable to store error message. The basic flow is like this.

```
class SMS{
      string message;
      public string getport(){
         if(ErrorCondition)
            message="Error Finding port";
         return port;         
      }
      public void executecommand(command){
         if(ErrorCondition1)
            message="Error Executing Command";
         else(ErrorCondition2)
            message="No Response from device";         
      }
      public void sendMessage(int number, string text, out string error){
           findport();
           executecommand(command);
           error = message;
      }
}
```

NB:This is not the working code

This is the way I have thought to collect error message, but I not sure if I am doing it the right way. I need your help on this. Is there a better approach? Error string does not save any string.
Update: As the answers of Exception are coming, I am confused about arrangement of try catch, here I have my actual code so that I'll help to give further suggestions.

```
public string ReadResponse(SerialPort port, int timeout)
{
    string buffer = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        do
        {
            if (receiveNow.WaitOne(timeout, false))
            {
               string t = port.ReadExisting();
               buffer += t;
            }
            else
            {
               if (buffer.Length > 0)
                   message = "Response incomplete";
               else
                   message = "Error on Modem";
             }
     }
     while (!buffer.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n") && !buffer.EndsWith("\r\n> ") && !buffer.EndsWith("\r\nERROR\r\n"));
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     throw ex;
 }
 return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your (pseudo) code can be refactored to use the de facto way of managing errors in C#, which are exceptions. Based on your code right there, you're used to using a special variable or return value as an error message and there's *nothing wrong with that*, it just won't be what other C# developers would expect.

Here's some (pseudo) code that demonstrates what I'm typing about.

```
class SMS {
    public string GetPort() {
        if (ErrorCondition) {
            throw new PortNotFoundException("Error finding port."); 
        }
        return port; 
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand(Command command) {
        if(ErrorCondition1) {
            throw new UnknownErrorException("Error Executing Command");
        }
        else(ErrorCondition2) {
            throw new NoResponseException("No Response from device"); 
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(int number, string text) {
        FindPort();
        ExecuteCommand(command); 
    }
}
```

You'll note that there's no `out` variable in `SendMessage` to handle passing out the error to calling code. That's handled by the thrown exceptions. The calling code is at liberty to determine how best to handle the exception.

Comment: can you suggest me further looking the update answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can declare

```
string message;
```

to

```
private List<string> message;
```

and add message to list, will help to catch multiple errors as well. Also make it private so that other class cant access the same.

Comment: the problem also exists while returning message from sendmessage function

Comment: its because in send message you are using out string error, which should  be out List<string> error.